# Batch script for compressing multiple files into separately output

Tags: batch-file

I'm having a little problem for compressing multiples files.

The problem is, if the file name is the same even not in the same folder, they are automatically compressing.

Here's the example of what I'm talking about.

```
Folder 1:
  JOHN 1.psd
  JOHN 2.psd
Folder 2
  JOHN 1.psd
  JOHN 2.psd
```

The problem output become like this, `JOHN 1.psd.rar`
and inside of that file, there is `JOHN 1.psd`, (from folder 1), and `JOHN 1.psd`, (from folder 2).

I want, to compress them in the same source folder even the same file from different folder. Because I'm doing so many files to compress.

Here's my script:

```
@echo off

:start
cls

set path="C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe"
set ext=psd
        
echo.
@echo off
for /r %%A in (*.%ext%) do (
    %path% a -r -ep -df "%%A.rar" "%%~nxA"
)
exit
```

Comment: ***Never*** use the system-reserved variable name `PATH`!! Anyway, as your question is not quite clear, please provide an example of what your archive(s) should contain based on your sample input files…

Comment: Thanks for correction. I already found the solution.

Comment: Then please either post an answer (which you should then accept) or delete the question…

Comment: @aschipfl if I post my answer, I might get banned  again. But I'll try

Comment: I reverted your last edit as answers need to be posted in the *answer* section. You should perhaps take the [tour] and visit the [help] in order to learn how to create quality posts, then you won't get banned. Also consult [Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) and [Why are answers no longer being accepted from my account?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans) to learn more about bans…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
    @echo off
    :start
    cls
    
    set WinrarDir="C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe"
    
    echo.
    @echo off
    for /r %%i in (*.psb) do ( 
      %WinrarDir% a -r -ep -df "%%i.rar" "%%i"
    )
    exit
```